# How to change the width of the columns in Firefox’s developer tools’ network tab

Tags: firefox, developer-tools, firefox-developer-tools

In Chrome, I can customize the width of the columns in its developer tools’ network tab:

[image: Chrome developer tools screenshot]

In Firefox, I can’t figure out how to do the same thing:

[image: Firefox developer tools screenshot]

Is it possible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Starting from Firefox 67](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1358414) it is possible to resize the columns within the Network Monitor.

Answer (score 1):

This feature is now available in **beta** version (v67.x). You will need to go to `about:config` and enable the flag `devtools.netmonitor.features.resizeColumns`.

*For previous versions see [Change columns size in Firefox Developer Tools](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47545994/3367974)*